# DataReader has rows and data, trying to read from it says "no data is present"

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I haven't used DataReaders in ages (I prefer to use an ORM) but I'm forced to at work.  I pull back the rows, and check that `HasRows` is true; debugging at this point and examining the reader shows that my data is there.

Now here's the issue: the moment I call `reader.Read()`, trying to expand the results says "The enumeration yielded no results" or whatever, and I get the "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present." error.  I get the same thing if I don't call `Read()` (which is the default since the DataReader starts before the first record).

I cannot remember the proper way to handle this; the data **is** there when I check `HasRows`, but is gone the moment I either try to read from it right after or after I call `Read`, which makes no sense as if I don't call `Read`, the reader should still be before the first record, and if the property is set that starts it at the first record (SingleRow?  I forget the name of it) is set, then I should be able to read rows without calling Read, however both ways seem to move *past* the row containing the data.

What am I forgetting?  Code is fairly straightforward:

```
TemplateFile file = null;
using (DbDataReader reader = ExecuteDataReaderProc("GetTemplateByID", idParam)) 
{ 
    if (reader.HasRows) // reader has data at this point - verified with debugger
    { 
        reader.Read(); // loses data at this point if I call Read()
        template = new TemplateFile 
        {
            FileName = Convert.ToString(reader["FileName"]) // whether or not I call
                                                            // Read, says no data here
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: does `reader.Read()` return `true` or `false` ? why not just use `if(reader.Read())` or `while(reader.Read())` ?

Comment: also - when you say "verified with debugger" ... how *exactly* ? (just trying to see if your test perhaps broke the data)

Comment: To confirm what @Marc has said, I had an issue in the past where hovering over a queryable variable caused the debugger to fetch the results, which then meant the code couldn't complete because you could only enumerate over the records once (which the debugger had done).  Could this be the same thing? (Could this also happen with Watches?)

Comment: @Marc I expand the `ResultsView` property, which shows a "DataRecordInternal" enumerable, which then has properties that, if I drill down enough, I can see the data returned.  It only works once though; after I drill down to ResultsView the first time all future tries says "The enumeration yielded no results" (which makes sense as it would move the data reader).  Also, yes `reader.Read()` returns true, but still says there's no data when I try to actually use a value; incidentally if I expand after calling Read() I still get "Enumeration yielded no results", but it has results during HasRows.

Comment: @Wayne - both calling Read() and drilling into that **change the state**, and it will no longer work. Don't do that (in this case). I think in this case: debugger considered harmful. So; what happens when you don't use the debugger / watch windows / etc?

Comment: @Smudge and @Marc it could be that, going to try now. **EDIT** Yep, seems to be the debugger.

Comment: @Smudge202 - +1 for queryable variable; you were a poet and you didn't even know it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to clarify the answer, it was using the debugger since expanding the results view calls `Read()` and therefore it moves past the row.  As Marc Gravell said in a comment: **Debugger considered harmful**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the data into a file, start by loading a DataTable instead of using a DataReader.
With the DataReader, as has been mentioned in the comments, you might want to iterate through the result set with a while loop

```
while (reader.Read())
{

}
```

The loop reads one row at a time and quits when all of the rows have been read.
Once you move to the next row, the previous rows are no longer available unless you have put them into some other structure, like a list or DataTable.

But you can use a DataAdapater to fill a DataTable so there might not be a reason to use a DataReader. Then you can write to a file from the DataTable.

In any event, I don't see how this line could work.

```
FileName = Convert.ToString(reader["FileName"])
```

I can post additional code for either approach if you like.
HTH Harvey Sather