# SqlDataReader does not read data inspite of data being there

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqldatareader

```
SqlDataReader rdItems;

SqlCommand itemsCmd = new SqlCommand();
itemsCmd.CommandText = query;
itemsCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
itemsCmd.Connection = sqlCon;

 sqlCon.Open();

 rdItems = itemsCmd.ExecuteReader();

 if (rdItems.HasRows)
 {   
     while (rdItems.Read())
     {
         itemType = rdItems["I1"].ToString();
```

Above is my code which I am using to read data from a `SqlDataReader`. The problem is data is there in `rdItems` but when `rdItems.Read()` line is getting executed, the rows from the reader disappears. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: are you getting any exception ?

Comment: no exception. just that the execution doesnt go in while loop.

Comment: What does your `query` look like?? And what do you mean by *the rows disappears* ?

Comment: @marc_s -  My query is something like this. query = "SELECT DISTINCT I1 FROM NewItems"; I get 15 rows. But when .Read() statement is executed then Enumeration Yielded no results comes. Reader gets empty.

Comment: Is three space between `I1` and `from` ?

Comment: sorry there is a space.

Comment: Have you checked if `rdItems.HasRows` returns true? *Edit: You can actually remove the if condition btw.

Comment: While debugging can u see `rdItems` what it contains ?

Comment: did you use `using` keyword with your connection ?

Comment: What is value of `TimeOut` for `SqlConnection` ?

Comment: @Leopard I assumed it's default but if it were a timeout issue, he'd get an exception anyways.

Comment: HasRows may return false when Read() would return SqlException; HasRows may be True but SqlException is not thrown until Read() is invoked; debug it, and check your query variable, copy paste and run it in sql server

Comment: Try rdItems.GetString(0);

Comment: expanding the results view in debugger calls Read() and therefore it moves past the row

Comment: You need to be careful: a reader can only be consumed once. By having the data visible in the preview window, it is entirely likely you've consumed that data accidentally in the debugger, and it is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `SqlDataReader` can only be consumed once after `ExecuteReader`, means that `while` loop iterates through the reader and simply quits when all rows finished to read. Thus when the loop moves to the next row after `HasRows` is checked, all previous rows are no longer available on the reader unless they're put into DataTable or a list.

By using a `DataTable`, you can check existence of DataReader content(s) and iterate them when any rows exist:

```
// assume your query like "SELECT DISTINCT I1 FROM NewItems"
// resulting single column with multiple distinct value rows

rdItems = itemsCmd.ExecuteReader();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(rdItems); // load DataReader contents to a DataTable, resulting an empty DataTable if no row exists

// check if datatable is not empty as substitute of SqlDataReader.HasRows property
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        // get row data
        itemType = row.Field<String>(0);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or improvements welcome.

Reference: [DataReader has rows and data, trying to read from it says "no data is present"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493955/datareader-has-rows-and-data-trying-to-read-from-it-says-no-data-is-present)