# SqlDataReader read() working unconscionability

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, sqldatareader

im getting data from the server as expected as you can see here (the data is not null)[image]

but it won't enter to `while (reader.Read())`

or sometimes after one or two iteration im getting the exception

```
"Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."
```

again, the data is not null

EDIT: added some code snippet

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
            try
            {
                sqlConnection = connectToDB();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT TOP 50 R.[RoundID] ,[DailyOrder] ,min(R.[RoundName]) as RoundName, min([EquipCode]) as TruckCode,
                                                sum(RD.[Weight]) as [Weight], RD.BlilCode, min(Blil.BlilName) as BlilName
                                                FROM [CVfeedDB].[dbo].[Planning.Rounds] as R 
                                                left join [CVfeedDB].[dbo].[Planning.RoundsDetail] as RD on R.RoundID = RD.RoundID 
                                                left join [CVfeedDB].[dbo].[constants.Blil] as Blil on RD.BlilCode = Blil.BlilCode  
                                                WHERE R.[ActionDate] = @ActionDate
                                                Group by R.[RoundID] ,[DailyOrder], RD.BlilCode  
                                                order by [DailyOrder]  ", sqlConnection);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                //string date = Convert.ToString();
                var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Variables().Item("Date Select").get_Value(0).ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
                var dt1 = dt.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActionDate",dt1 );
                string prefix = "";
                int i = 1;
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    prefix = ordersName + i.ToString() + "]";
                    List<object> list = new List<object>();
                    List<object> IDList = new List<object>();
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Variables().Item(prefix + ".LoopID").get_Value(0));
                    int k = reader.GetInt32(0);

                    if (id == 0 || id == k)//if no id or we are writing the same id                        
                    {
                        Variables().Item(prefix + ".LoopID").set_Value(0, reader.GetInt32(0));
                        //Variables().Item(prefix + ".").set_Value(0, reader.GetInt32(1));      //Order sequence
                        Variables().Item(prefix + ".LoopName").set_Value(0, reader.GetString(2));
                        Variables().Item(prefix + ".Truck").set_Value(0, Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetString(3)));
                        Variables().Item(prefix + ".Weight").set_Value(0, Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetDecimal(4)));
                        Variables().Item(prefix + ".MixID").set_Value(0, Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetString(5)));
                        Variables().Item(prefix + ".MixName").set_Value(0, reader.GetString(6));
                    }
```

please not that `Variables().Item(...)` it how I communicate with 3rd party software

Comment: what code did you try? show your code sample.

Comment: @InnovaITveSolutions added some code snippet

Comment: You're performing `LEFT JOIN`s and then returning some columns directly from those tables without even considering aggregates. You *have* to anticipate that, in some rows, some values *will* be `NULL` but your code doesn't currently protect from that situation.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever as i said i checked the result in the DB and there are no null(s) what so ever in the results

Comment: Plainly, ADO.NET disagrees with you. It doesn't randomly assign error message strings to exceptions. It **is** reading a `NULL`. There's insufficient context here for anyone *else* to debug this situation. You're the only one with a complete set of runnable code and your actual data. We can't help as this currently stands. If you're able to, please create a [mcve].

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever please explain why ADO.NET does not agree with me, there are values in the result (i can see it the reader), also sometimes it does enter to the while `loop` and sometimes not **on the same query**

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493955/datareader-has-rows-and-data-trying-to-read-from-it-says-no-data-is-present) guy had a issue using the debugger as it moved the datareader to the next position. [DataReader has rows and data, trying to read from it says “no data is present"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493955/datareader-has-rows-and-data-trying-to-read-from-it-says-no-data-is-present)

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that your SqlConnection is null. It will always return null value.

Secondally
You should check the reader has rows like i m using reader.Hasrows

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
                try
                {
                    sqlConnection = connectToDB();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT TOP 50 R.[RoundID] ,[DailyOrder] ,min(R.[RoundName]) as RoundName, min([EquipCode]) as TruckCode,
                                                    sum(RD.[Weight]) as [Weight], RD.BlilCode, min(Blil.BlilName) as BlilName
                                                    FROM [CVfeedDB].[dbo].[Planning.Rounds] as R 
                                                    left join [CVfeedDB].[dbo].[Planning.RoundsDetail] as RD on R.RoundID = RD.RoundID 
                                                    left join [CVfeedDB].[dbo].[constants.Blil] as Blil on RD.BlilCode = Blil.BlilCode  
                                                    WHERE R.[ActionDate] = @ActionDate
                                                    Group by R.[RoundID] ,[DailyOrder], RD.BlilCode  
                                                    order by [DailyOrder]  ", sqlConnection);
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    //string date = Convert.ToString();
                    var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Variables().Item("Date Select").get_Value(0).ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
                    var dt1 = dt.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActionDate",dt1 );
                    string prefix = "";
                    int i = 1;
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if(reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        prefix = ordersName + i.ToString() + "]";
                        List<object> list = new List<object>();
                        List<object> IDList = new List<object>();
                        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Variables().Item(prefix + ".LoopID").get_Value(0));
                        int k = reader.GetInt32(0);

                        if (id == 0 || id == k)//if no id or we are writing the same id                        
                        {
                            Variables().Item(prefix + ".LoopID").set_Value(0, reader.GetInt32(0));
                            //Variables().Item(prefix + ".").set_Value(0, reader.GetInt32(1));      //Order sequence
                            Variables().Item(prefix + ".LoopName").set_Value(0, reader.GetString(2));
                            Variables().Item(prefix + ".Truck").set_Value(0, Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetString(3)));
                            Variables().Item(prefix + ".Weight").set_Value(0, Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetDecimal(4)));
                            Variables().Item(prefix + ".MixID").set_Value(0, Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetString(5)));
                            Variables().Item(prefix + ".MixName").set_Value(0, reader.GetString(6));
                        }
                      }
              }
```

Comment: First. in the `connectToDB();` function I'm connecting to the DB (and I checked that the status is open). seconds. `reader.HasRows` always passes. Third: as I said I checked the reader and it has values

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
string namethestore = myReader.IsDBNull(namePos) 
                                          ? string.Empty 
                                          : reader.GetString(reader.GetString(2));

 Variables().Item(prefix + ".LoopName").set_Value(0, namethestore);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added `isNull(rowname, 0 )` to the problematic rows and it solved my problem